# How do I iterate through multiple LU decompositions to solve Ax = b with different b vectors?

Tags: matlab

I am currently doing practice MatLab problems and I am stuck on this problem which involves a truss bridge. It is asking me to add weight to the truck parked at node 9 in increments of 0.1, starting with the weight w9 = 13000 and increasing to some large weight until the bridge collapses. Each beam can withstand 20000 Newtons of force (positive or negative). Therefore the bridge will collapse when any one forces is larger than 20000 in magnitude, or equivalently when
the maximum of the absolute values of all forces is greater than or equal to 20000.

I am using a for loop to iterate through the weights W9 = 13000.0, 13000.1, 13000.2, . . . and so on to solve the
system Ax = b repeatedly for the forces within the bridge, until the force on at least one of the beams exceeds the breaking point. I am using LU decomposition to solve the system efficiently.

```
A = [-0.5 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 0 0; 
-sqrt(3)/2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -sqrt(3)/2 0 0 0 0 0;
0 -1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5 0.5 0 0 0; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -sqrt(3)/2 -sqrt(3)/2 0 0 0;
0 0 -1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5 0.5 0; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -sqrt(3)/2 -sqrt(3)/2 0; 
0 0 0 -1 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5; 
0 0 0 0 -sqrt(3)/2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -sqrt(3)/2; 
0 0 0 0 -0.5 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5; 
0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5 0.5; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 sqrt(3)/2 sqrt(3)/2; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 0 0 0 -0.5 0.5 0 0; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 sqrt(3)/2 sqrt(3)/2 0 0; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 -0.5 0.5 0 0 0 0; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 sqrt(3)/2 sqrt(3)/2 0 0 0 0];

w7 = 800;
w8 = 900;
w9 = 13000;
W = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; w7; 0; w8; 0; w9];

for kk = w9:0.1:20000
    for jj = 1:15
        [L,U,P] = lu(A);
         Y = L\(P*W);
         X = U\Y;
         if abs(X(jj,1)) > 20000
             break
         end
    end
end
save('A.dat','w9','-ascii')
save('B.dat','X','-ascii')
```

When I ran it, w9 did not change at all and I ended up with same vector X. I expected it to iterate for a while before the loop actually breaks, but it ends up not doing so. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: You don’t use `kk` in your computations. Every loop iteration you compute exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the additional "weight" to `w9`, or anywhere else it is relevant, and redefine `W`. Otherwise nothing changes in your loop...

I've optimised your code slightly, as you didn't need the inner loop.

Finally, you need to run to a higher `w9`. Your condition isn't met until `w9 = 22228`.

```
w7 = 800;
w8 = 900;
w9_initial = 13000;

for w9 = w9_initial:0.1:25000  
    % Define W with the increased w9   
    W = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; w7; 0; w8; 0; w9];
    % Calculate. These calculations aren't dependent on jj, so no point having a loop
    [L,U,P] = lu(A);
    Y = L\(P*W);
    X = U\Y;
    if any( abs( X ) > 20000 )
         break
    end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't break the loop at the specific w9 when one of the elements of X has a magnitude greater than 20000. I tried this solution multiple times, but it keeps looping all the way through.